# generic open form function

Tags: vb.net, winforms, generics

has anyone written a generic "LaunchForm" function? For all the menu items I have that open a form, I would like to write one function that will launch the form as opposed to writing the same code several times.

any tips would be very helpful.

It's winforms + vb.net

thanks
TR

Comment: I suggest you post the code you have to write over and over again so we can help in making it Generic.

Comment: Dim childForm As New "FormName" 
childForm.MdiParent = Me
childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
childForm.Show()
"FormName" is one of 30 different forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

*C#*

```
public F Launch<F>() where F : Form, new()
{
    F dlg = new F();
    dlg.MdiParent = this;
    dlg.Show();
    return dlg;
}
```

*VB.NET*

```
Public Function Launch(Of F As {Form, New})() As F
    Dim dlg As New F()
    dlg.MdiParent = Me
    dlg.Show()
    Return dlg
End Function
```

Comment: that looks about right. 
what would public F Launch<F>() where F : Form, new()
translated into vb be?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the form type to the menuitem's .Tag property.  Hook up a single event handler to all the menu item click events and pass the .Tag property value (form type) to a function that created a new instance and displayed it.

Alternately, if each form is to be a singleton you could create a dictionary of(MenuItem, Form), prepopulate with form instances and do the appropriate lookup/show.  Or even skip the dictionary and pop and instance of the form into the menuitem's .Tag property.

There's all kinds of options and without knowing the intended usage it's hard to suggest just one.