# vb.net - how to open the same form multiple times USING A SUB

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

You probably think this is a duplicate of other questions about this. But it isn't

I have seen several different questions about this but none of them answer this.

I would to open a form multiple times USING A SUB. Where I pass in a `Form` and it creates a new instance of this form. However I keep having problems with the `Form` being disposed if I run it twice

This is the sub that does not work:

```
Public Shared Sub OpenProgram(ByRef formToOpen As Form)
    Dim newApp As Form
    newApp = formToOpen
    Try
        newApp.Show()
        newApp.BringToFront()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to open program :(")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have also tried `Dim newApp As New Form` and 
`Dim newApp As New formToOpen` however none of these work

I only have the problem if I try and run the sub, then close the form, then run the sub again.

The error I get is:

> Can not access a disposed object 
>  Object Name: 'shop'

`shop` is just a form

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's `shop` ? your code doesn't have anything with this name.

Comment: Shop is just a form

Comment: code snippet you shared seems to be okay, issue must be in code which is being used to call this sub.

Comment: It is being called right here: `OpenProgram(shop)`

Comment: The problem is that when you close the form it becomes disposed - meaning you can't show it

Comment: If you want to create multiple instances of tour form, then you should instantiate it in OpenProgram like Dim form As New Form form.Show()

Comment: When you close the form it does *not* become disposed. If it did, it would not be possible to examine its values which would render `ShowDialog` useless. It is therefore not clear [what you in fact want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640). If you need to clone an existing instance of a form, that could be tricky because you need to recreate values of all controls. If you want to create a new form of certain type, you should pass the type, not an instance of that type.

Comment: All I want to be able to do is just open the same form multiple times in a sub where I pass the value of `form` in.

Comment: Open the same form or several instances of the same type? And in any case, why do you pass an existing form?

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do. The whole point of this sub is that it opens a new instance of the form I pass in. So, for example - let's say I have a form called `shop` what I would like to be able to do is use `OpenProgram(shop)` and for the sub to open a new instance of `shop`. I would then like to be able to do this AGAIN while `shop` is open and have TWO shops, both open at the same time!

Comment: The reason I pass in an existing `form` is to make it so I could do the same with... `pong` (which is another form)

Comment: @GSerg - If a `Form` is shown using `form.Show`, then it is automatically disposed when it is closed.  As you alluded, showing the form using `ShowDialog` will prevent it from being automatically disposed when closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option one, [with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748292/11683):

```
Public Function OpenProgram(Of F As {Form, New})(ByVal ThisOne As F) As F
    Return New F()
End Function
```

Option two, [without generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33391192/11683):

```
Public Function OpenProgram(ByVal ThisOne As Form) As Form
    Return CType(Activator.CreateInstance(ThisOne.GetType()), Form)
End Function
```

---

Usage:

```
Dim newApp As Form = OpenProgram(shop)
newApp.Show
```

Comment: They both work. You probably did something very wrong.

Comment: Well option 1 just showed a completely blank form but anyway, that doesn't matter - it works now!

Answer (score 3):

Given a master form with 2 buttons and the following code, and two other forms, the buttons can be clicked repeatedly to open multiples of the forms, and closing them has no effect on opening more.

```
Public Class MasterForm
    Private Sub btnOpenForm1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm1.Click
        ShowForm(New Form1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOpenForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm2.Click
        ShowForm(New Form2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowForm(WhichForm As Form)
        With WhichForm
            .Show()
            .BringToFront()
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You posted this just as I got the answer

Comment: Thank you, that worked just fine

Answer (score -2):

Your "closed " form is not closed until you dispose of it, it is just not shown. You need to loop through your forms and show the form that you want to view again. You will probably use something like this -

```
Private Sub cmdOpenForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  cmdOpenForm.Click

    Dim frmCollection = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms
    If frmCollection.OfType(Of frmShop).Any Then
        frmCollection.Item("frmShop").Activate()
    Else
        Dim frmShop As New frmShop
        frmShop.Show()
    End If

    Me.Close()
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

The close and dispose part is pointing to the form you are currently in. As forms are objects you need to activate them again for them to be used or you need to recreate them again to show a new instance of that form.

Hope this is what you were looking for.